# Jquery how to run a function in multiple places

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops

I am fairly new to Javascript and Im trying to write some jquery that compares two dates.  If the number of days compared is less than or equal to a number, than i want some classes to be added to the `LI` child elements of a parent named `.momentum-container`.

When the script runs on one `DIV` container it works as expected, the problem is when I add additional `DIV` containers. I am trying to call a function to read the contents of the `.momentum-container` and run the script, find the next `.momentum-container` and do the same. Instead it looks like its reading the contents of the first container only, and duplicating the results.

In the fiddle you can see the two rows of 7 bars.  The top row should have 7 bars, the bottom row should only have 3 bars.  Instead there are two rows of 7.

Any help is much appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/j1qs3gr0/14/

```
// prototype to compare two dates
Date.prototype.DaysBetween = function () {
    var intMilDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var intMilDif = arguments[0] - this;
    var intDays = Math.floor(intMilDif / intMilDay);
    return intDays;
};

today = 12 + '/' + 17 + '/' + 2014;

// function that calculates the momentum

function calcMomentum(currentPost, olderPost) {
    var current = $(currentPost).val();
    var older = $(olderPost).val();
    var todayD = new Date(today);
    var postD = new Date(current);
    var otherD = new Date(older);

// compare dates
    var resistance = (postD.DaysBetween(todayD));
    var movement = (otherD.DaysBetween(postD));
    var momomentum = (resistance + movement);

// function uses the above variables to apply classes if condition is met
    $(".momentum").each(function () {
        if (momomentum <= 6) {
            $(this).children("li.two").addClass("level-two");
        }

        if (momomentum <= 5) {
            $(this).children("li.three").addClass("level-three");
        }

        if (momomentum <= 4) {
            $(this).children("li.four").addClass("level-four");
        }

        if (momomentum <= 3) {
            $(this).children("li.five").addClass("level-five");
        }

        if (momomentum <= 2) {
            $(this).children("li.six").addClass("level-six");
        }

        if (momomentum <= 1) {
            $(this).children("li.seven").addClass("level-seven");
        }

    });

}

$(".momentum-container").each(function () {
    calcMomentum(".js-post-date", ".js-older-date");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always iterate through parent element when there are multiple elements.

Try this:

## Working Example [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mangesh/j1qs3gr0/19/)

```
// prototype to compare two dates
Date.prototype.DaysBetween = function () {
    var intMilDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var intMilDif = arguments[0] - this;
    var intDays = Math.floor(intMilDif / intMilDay);
    return intDays;
};

today = 12 + '/' + 17 + '/' + 2014;

// function that calculates the momentum
function calcMomentum(currentPost, olderPost, parent) {

    var current = $(currentPost,parent).val();
    var older = $(olderPost,parent).val();
    var todayD = new Date(today);
    var postD = new Date(current);
    var otherD = new Date(older);
    
    // compare dates
    var resistance = (postD.DaysBetween(todayD));
    var movement = (otherD.DaysBetween(postD));
    var momomentum = (resistance + movement);

    // function uses the above variables to apply classes if condition is met
    $(".momentum",parent).each(function () {

        if (momomentum <= 6) {

            $(this).children("li.two").addClass("level-two");
        }

        if (momomentum <= 5) {
            $(this).children("li.three").addClass("level-three");
        }

        if (momomentum <= 4) {
            $(this).children("li.four").addClass("level-four");
        }

        if (momomentum <= 3) {
            $(this).children("li.five").addClass("level-five");
        }

        if (momomentum <= 2) {
            $(this).children("li.six").addClass("level-six");
        }

        if (momomentum <= 1) {
            $(this).children("li.seven").addClass("level-seven");
        }

    });

}

$(".momentum-container").each(function () {
    calcMomentum(".js-post-date", ".js-older-date", $(this));
});
```